# Range out of order in character class on regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, typescript

I am trying to create a regex class from this pattern like this:

```
let regex:RegExp = RegExp(/^(?:[\x{c0}-\x{1ff}a-zA-Z\'-]){2,}(?:\s[\x{c0}-\x{1ff}a-zA-Z\',.-]{2,})+$/, 'iu');
```

I took it from an earlier project I did with PHP and I know it works there. However, it does not work here:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?:[\x{c0}-\x{1ff}a-zA-Z\'-]){2,}(?:\s[\x{c0}-\x{1ff}a-zA-Z\',.-]{2,})+$/: Range out of order in character class
```

My environment runs on nodejs 6.

Can anyone help me fix this? thanks.

Comment: Try removing bits of the regex until it compiles, the last one you removed is the one that broke the regex

Comment: Try it like `/^(?:[\u{c0}-\u{1ff}a-zA-Z'-]){2,}(?:\s[\u{c0}-\u{1ff}a-zA-Z',.-]{2,})+$/u`